# Android send notifications at greatly increasing intervals

Tags: java, android, jobservice

I am writing a reminder app for Android that repeatedly sends the user a notification with increasing intervals in between. Namely after 30s, 2m, 10m, ..., 25 days, 4 months, 2 years.

I originally intended to do this by registering a `JobService` that would run every 30s to check whether it was time to send a notification. However, as [this post](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742) warns (and as I found out):

[image]

Which means that my job runs *at most* once every 15 minutes, and prevents me from sending my 30s, 2m and 10m reminders.

**What would be the correct/most efficient way of implementing such functionality?**
*(Also, running a job every 30s to check for the 2y notification is quite inefficient)*

Comment: schedule next after finishing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it a periodic job. Make each next schedule a one-time event. Each time the job is triggered schedule a new item.

Comment: Which class/API would you recommend that I use?

Comment: The class to use is AlarmManager. The idea is that you create a service that performs the scheduled task's work. The service also, each time it is run, schedules its next run. I think you can use AlarmManager.set() to schedule the service to run at an arbitrary time.